# How do I define multiple table definitions and multiple column specs for cassandra-stress profile file?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1, cassandra-stress

```
# Keyspace Name
keyspace: demo1

# The CQL for creating a keyspace (optional if it already exists)
keyspace_definition: |
  CREATE KEYSPACE demo1;
# Table name
table: sample_test

# The CQL for creating a table you wish to stress (optional if it already exists)
table_definition: |
    CREATE TABLE sample_test (
        key1 blob PRIMARY KEY,
        value1 blob
    )

### Column Distribution Specifications ###

columnspec:
  - name: hash
    size: fixed(96)       #domain names are relatively short

  - name: body
    size: gaussian(100..300)    #the body of the blog post can be long
    population: uniform(1..10M)  #10M possible domains to pick from
```

Now how do I define another table within the same keyspace? All examples talk about just defining one table. I tried also defining another table definition and its column spec just like above but then I get the following error "com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Batch too large"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot. A stress profile can contain only one `table_definition` and it can only have one table defined in it. It even verifies that theres only one definition matching the `table` declaration. You could try running two instances of the stress tool at same time to get that behavior, its inconvenient but I think its the only workaround available short of writing own benchmark (which is tricky).

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been raised on Cassandra https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8780

It has been fixed but will only be released with the next major version of Cassandra (4.0).